# calling Servlet from jsp <href> link is not working

Tags: jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc, servlets, logout

i am working on a spring mvc project and i have used Tomcat FORM authentication for login.
and the application is working fine so now i am working on the logout implementation.
the application is having home page (home.jsp) with logout link and i am trying to call a LogoutServlet as below.

### LogoutServlet.java

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/logout"})
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet  {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest  request,HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      // To logout the current user
      request.getSession().invalidate();

    // The user is now logged out so redirect the user to the welcome.jsp page .
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/welcome.jsp");
  }
```

}

### home.jsp

```
<body>      

    <a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>

        <form:form id="formDataBean" method="post" modelAttribute="formDataBean" action="submit" class="form" >

        //form body
        .
        .

        </form:form>
</body>
```

### web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,classpath*:gameResult-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <security-constraint>

    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>

  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login-failed</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>



 // i have a doubt on the below code as i don't know if it has to be there at all
 // because when ever i start the application (server) this servlet gets initialize 
 // and doGet() gets execute.

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.sample.servlets.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logout/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**here is the problem :**
i want to call the LogoutServlet from logout link and redirect to welcome.jsp page but right now its not working, its throwing HTTP Status 404 error `(http://localhost:8080/gameResult/LogoutServlet).`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your Servlet, you should probably call `http://localhost:8080/gameResult/logout` instead.

```
<a href="logout">Logout</a>
```

You could add automatically context to elimitate further problems if you use this code in another path, this way you won't have to bother about relative path.

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
```

Also, you should remove this stuff from `web.xml` :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.sample.servlets.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/logout/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Because you are using `WebServlet` annotation.

Comment: Many many thanks @Alexandre for your answer, i have used <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a> and removed the LogoutServlet from web.xml and its working fine.

Comment: @Soumyaansh Don't forget to go trought your questions and mark as answered if they are!

Comment: why we need to add contextPath `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` href will be generating a GET request itself, so the webcontainer should be calling the appropriate servlet for the given _url-pattern_ isn't it? Can you please explain the difference??

Comment: Because the href was relative, it means it will load the url by appending "logout" to current url. If you are at `http://localhost/context/somepath/` it will load `http://localhost/context/somepath/logout` but the `url-pattern` will match only `http://localhost/context/logout`, so either you never change path (always referencing to `context-path`, or you give the full path by using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.